# Pixels in YUV image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, yuv

I am using opencv to achieve object tracking. I read that YUV image is better option to use than RGB image. My problem is that I fail to understand about the YUV format although i spend much time read notes. Y is the brightness which i believe is calculated from the combination of R, G, B component.

My main problem is how can I access and manipulate the pixels in YUV image format. In RGB format its easy to access the component and therefore change it using simple operatin like

```
src.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0] = 0; for example
```

But this is not the case in YUV. I need help in accessing and changing the pixel values in YUV image. For example if pixel in RGB is red, then I want to only keep the corresponding pixel in YUV and the rest is removed. Please help me with this.

Comment: In what **context** is YUV *better* than RGB? If you want to filter red pixels, I recommend RGB (for simple images) or HSV (for natural images).

Comment: Because the illuminations of the photos many vary therefore I thought that YUV could be a better option

Comment: Most cameras actually capture in YCbCr (very similar, and sometimes treated as identical to YUV), so if you set up the camera controls correctly using OpenCV then you can access this YCbCr image directly. I'm working on a system now that does object detection in images, and so far we've found labelling images in the HSV colour space to be the most successful. I've read that LAB space can also give good results, depending upon the problem.

Comment: @DrewNoakes the images u used for object detection are in controlled environment or uncontrolled

Comment: @user1965914, it's a controlled environment with quite vibrant colours.

Comment: In terms of RGB image the illuminations vastly affects the pixel values as i am aware. SO in your environment is the illumination all around constant. Sorry if I am too confusing.

Comment: My understanding is that most cameras use YUV because the human eye is more sensitive to changes in luminance (brightness) than changes in chrominance (colour). A computer vision system probably does not care about this. At any rate, in the HSV space you find that 'similar' colours tend to be closer together than they are in RGB. Or said another way, the 3D distance between two colours in HSV is closer to what a human comprehends than in RGB.

Comment: Thank you that was clear. Now going to my problem where I have images of 3 colored objects in different lighting conditions. They are in RGB format. By your suggestion i presume that HSV is the best option I should you rather than YUV.

Comment: @user1965914, yes I would suggest trying to do your image segmentation in HSV rather than RGB.

Comment: @DrewNoakes Many Cameras use YCbCr instead of RGB because it enables more efficient storage and compression of the image. Our eyes are not sensitive to changes in Cb Cr so often the image is stored in YUV422 or YUV420 formats which enable storing using merely 16 bits or 12 bits per pixel respectively instead of 24bits per pixel for RGB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest operating on your image in HSV or LAB rather than RGB.

The raw image from the camera will be in YCbCr (sometimes called YUV, which I think is incorrect, but I may be wrong), and laid out in a way that resembles something like YUYV (repeating), so if you can convert directly from that to HSV, you will avoid additional copy and conversion operations which will save you some time. That may only matter to you if you're processing video or batches of images however.

Here's some C++ code for converting between YCbCr and RGB (one uses integer math, the other floating point):

```
Colour::bgr Colour::YCbCr::toBgrInt() const
{
  int c0 = 22987;
  int c1 = -11698;
  int c2 = -5636;
  int c3 = 29049;

  int y = this->y;
  int cb = this->cb - 128;
  int cr = this->cr - 128;

  int b = y + (((c3 * cb) + (1 << 13)) >> 14);
  int g = y + (((c2 * cb + c1 * cr) + (1 << 13)) >> 14);
  int r = y + (((c0 * cr) + (1 << 13)) >> 14);

  if (r < 0)
    r = 0;
  else if (r > 255)
    r = 255;

  if (g < 0)
    g = 0;
  else if (g > 255)
    g = 255;

  if (b < 0)
    b = 0;
  else if (b > 255)
    b = 255;

  return Colour::bgr(b, g, r);
}

Colour::bgr Colour::YCbCr::toBgrFloat() const
{
  float y = this->y;
  float cb = this->cb;
  float cr = this->cr;

  int r = y + 1.40200 * (cr - 0x80);
  int g = y - 0.34414 * (cb - 0x80) - 0.71414 * (cr - 0x80);
  int b = y + 1.77200 * (cb - 0x80);

  if (r < 0)
    r = 0;
  else if (r > 255)
    r = 255;

  if (g < 0)
    g = 0;
  else if (g > 255)
    g = 255;

  if (b < 0)
    b = 0;
  else if (b > 255)
    b = 255;

  return Colour::bgr(b, g, r);
}
```

And a conversion from BGR to HSV:

```
Colour::hsv Colour::bgr2hsv(bgr const& in)
{
  Colour::hsv out;

  int const hstep = 255 / 3;            // Hue step size between red -> green -> blue

  int min = in.r < in.g ? in.r : in.g;
  min = min  < in.b ? min  : in.b;

  int max = in.r > in.g ? in.r : in.g;
  max = max  > in.b ? max  : in.b;

  out.v = max;                          // v
  int chroma = max - min;
  if (max > 0)
  {
    out.s = 255 * chroma / max;         // s
  }
  else
  {
    // r = g = b = 0                    // s = 0, v is undefined
    out.s = 0;
    out.h = 0;
    out.v = 0; // it's now undefined
    return out;
  }

  if (chroma == 0)
  {
    out.h = 0;
    return out;
  }

  const int chroma2 = chroma * 2;
  int offset;
  int diff;

  if (in.r == max)
  {
    offset = 3 * hstep;
    diff = in.g - in.b;
  }
  else if (in.g == max)
  {
    offset = hstep;
    diff = in.b - in.r;
  }
  else
  {
    offset = 2 * hstep;
    diff = in.r - in.g;
  }

  int h = offset + (diff * (hstep + 1)) / chroma2;

  // Rotate such that red has hue 0
  if (h >= 255)
    h -= 255;

  assert(h >= 0 && h < 256);

  out.h = h;

  return out;
```

Unfortunately I do not have code to do this in one step.

You can also use the [built-in OpenCV functions for colour conversion](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

```
cvtColor(img, img, CV_BGR2HSV);
```

Comment: Thank you. Actually i am using opencv and converting it to HSV. But your code is of great help as i am understand the basic method of conversion. Because my images (frames ) are still images, in RGB format, therefore I think I will convert it to HSV from RGB since time is not an issue for me at the moment. However, I realized some thing that has taken me by surprise. That is, if i convert to YUV visually I think the object color feature of interest becomes more relevant. Unfortunately maybe i am incorrect but I am confused over the use of which one. At the moment I am using HSV.

Comment: I am thinking to try both and than see which is better. In that case i will share the outcome with you.

Comment: are not built-in functions for color conversion better to use ?

Comment: It depends on your situation and how you define better.

Answer (score 1):

Also the U and V components are calculated as linear combinations of RGB values. Then it means, that different intensities of red (R,0,0) are mapped to some (y*R + a,u*R + b, v*R + c), which again means that to detect "red" in YUV one can calculate if the distance of the pixel to that line determined by y,u,v,a,b,c (some of which are redundant) is close to zero. That's achievable with a single dot product. Then set the remaining pixels to the (0,128,128) in YUV space (I think that's R=0,G=0,B=0 in almost all varieties of YCrCb, YUV and such).

Answer (score 1):

There are several YUV formats, but the common ones keep Y at the same resolution as the original image, but U and V are half size, and are saved as separate or interlaced planes/channels after the single channel Y image buffer.

This allows you to efficiently access Y as a 1-channel 8-bit greyscale image.

Comment: Maybe i am still little confused although you explained well. I understand Y is single channel but assume i have red pixel so RGB = {255,0,0}. Further i want to change this red to green lets say. How can i change Y based on this. Sorry if i sound too confusing

Comment: Y is a combination of R, G and B. It is the image intensity (or lightness) the greyscale version of the image. If you want to switch color channels you should convert to RGB and work in that space.

Answer (score 0):

Access and manipulate pixels does not know the colorformat so the same code applies for color components Y U and V. If you need to access in RGB mode, best is probably calling `cv::cvtColor` for your region of interest first.